# Addind months to a specific java.sql.Date date

Tags: java

How to add a specific number of months to a Date stored in a database.

```
private Date getStartDate(){
        return new Date(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
}

private Date getEndDate(){
    startDate = userSubscription.getSubscriptionStartDate();
    Date endDate;
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    //Now I am having trouble cause in add() method of calendar there is no long type parameter
    return endDate;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "no long type parameter"?

Answer (score 1):

<s>for example you can add 1 month by:</s>

```
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1);
```

Simply cast your variable (I assume number of months) to int.

I recommend to use different time library, for instance joda's. You can do something like that in joda library:

```
Date date = new Date();
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(date);
dateTime.plusMonths(1);
return dateTime.toDate();
```

Comment: That's not going to work very well if you wrap around the end of a year. This is precisely what `add` is for.

Comment: I agree, sory for mistake.

Answer (score 0):

First a side note - this code would also work to return a new date in your "getStartDate" method:

```
return new Date();
```

To answer your question:

```
calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, x);
endDate = calendar.getTime();
```

Where 'x' represents the number of months to add.

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid the last day of the month or last month of the year you could use [GregorianCalendar#roll(..)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#roll(int,%20int)). A possible way of rewriting your code:

```
private Date getEndDate(){
    //...
    Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
    //Now I am having trouble cause in add() method of calendar there is no long type parameter
    c.setTime(userSubscription.getSubscriptionStartDate());
    c.roll(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
    return c.getTime();
}
```